# Cocoapods how to set build setting based on configuration in the podspec

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Im trying to set a build configuration setting on my cocoapod im working on but I can only do it in a really inconvenient way, im trying to see if there is a better way doing it via the podspec file. Currently I have this in my example project pod file:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'MySDK'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if config.name == 'Test'
          config.build_settings['SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS'] = 'TEST'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which gives me what I want, which looks like this:

[image: correct build settings]

I've tried going like this (after removing the previous solution above from the pod file) inside my podspec file, a lot of SO answers say this should work but it doesnt seem to

```
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS[config=Test]' => 'TEST'
  }
```

it lands up looking like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me achieve this in my podspec file as apposed to the 3rd parties pod file?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS[config=Test][sdk=*][arch=*]' => 'TEST'
}
```